# Havard and hyperref do not like each other

Tags: hyperref, natbib, harvard-style, href

A journal has indicated that submissions can use the harvard bibliography style.  But it appears that the harvard style does not play well with hyperref or bookmarks (and maybe other packages that define \href).  If the `\usepackage{hyperref}` is commented out below (`%\usepackage{hyperref}`) the file compiles fine but hyperlinks in the bibliography (and elsewhere) do not work.  (natbib solves this problem but creates others)

```
% No matter how many times you compile this file, there is a warning message indicating
% that 'Label(s) have changed.  Re-run to get cross-references right
% Commenting out the hyperref package fixes the problem. But this means that links
% will not work properly (and many other widely used features will not be available)
\documentclass[AEJ]{AEA}
\usepackage[abbr]{harvard}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{hrsHabit}
\bibliographystyle{aea}
\bibliography{mwe}

\end{document}
```

Below is the corresponding bibfile mwe.bib

```
@article{hrsHabit,
  author =        {Havranek, Tomas and Rusnak, Marek and Sokolova, Anna},
  journal =       {European Economic Review},
  pages =         {142--167},
  publisher =     {Elsevier},
  title =         {Habit formation in consumption: A meta-analysis},
  volume =        {95},
  year =          {2017},
  doi =           {10.1016/j.euroecorev.2017.03.009},
  url =           {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.euroecorev.2017.03.009},
}
```

Comment: Works for me with some random version of the documentclass and bibstyle found on the internet. Can you link to the exact same version of the files you use?

Comment: Version of the AEA package I used was obtained [from the AEA website](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/policies/templates), the latex_templates.zip file.

Comment: Just tried it on a Ubuntu 18.04 install of TeXLive, same problem.  But it's easy to overlook the problem.  Briefly, if you do `pdflatex mwe; bibtex mwe; pdflatex mwe; pdflatex mwe` the log of the last file still produces "LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed.  Rerun to get cross-references right" in the (copious) output.  And continues to produce that warning no matter how many times you redo the bibtex and pdflatex.

Comment: The Natbib readme says it supports hyperref but the Harvard doc say it builds its own hyperlinks I have not tested however I guess the answer is use the Nat bib format if you want to use hyperref